# Apache Shiro в unit test

Tags: apache, сессия

Делаю тест на сессию пример взял от сюда [shiro](https://shiro.apache.org/testing.html)

> ```
> @Test
> public void testSimple()
> ```

переделал

```
@Test
public void testSimple() {

    //1.  Create a mock authenticated Subject instance for the test to run:
    Subject subjectUnderTest = createNiceMock(Subject.class);
    expect(subjectUnderTest.getSession()).andReturn(new SimpleSession());

    //2. Bind the subject to the current thread:
    setSubject(subjectUnderTest);

    Session session = SecurityUtils.getSubject().getSession;
}
```

Пробовал и так

> [[[@Test](/users/1155/test)](/users/1155/test)](/users/1155/test) public void testSimple() {
>
> ```
> //1.  Create a mock authenticated Subject instance for the test to run:
> Subject subjectUnderTest = createNiceMock(Subject.class);
> Session sessionMock= createNiceMock(sessionMock.class);
> expect(subjectUnderTest.getSession()).andReturn(sessionMock);
>
> //2. Bind the subject to the current thread:
> setSubject(subjectUnderTest);
>
> Session session = SecurityUtils.getSubject().getSession;
> ```
>
> }

Почему session у меня null получается?

Comment: Забыл скобки поставить, факт не меняется

Answer (score 1):

```
getSubject().getSession -> getSubject().getSession()
```